# Use of undefined constant PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, undefined

I've looked at other similar questions about this topic, but I couldn't find what am I missing.

I am trying to convert my mysql_ codes to the PDO, but although first part is very simple yet I couldn't deal with it. What am I doing wrong?
Also I have to use utf8, otherwise I'm getting characters problem.

So my issue is:

> Use of undefined constant IL_ADI assumed 'IL_ADI'

I've tried $oku['IL_ADI'] and no data was returned.

```
$dab = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=datauser; charset=utf8" ,'user_user' , 'password');
$dab->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$dab->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$query = 'SELECT * FROM iller ORDER BY IL_ADI';

$result= $dab->query($query);
while($oku=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

    print_r ("<option name='ilsec' value=''");
    print_r ($oku[IL_ADI]);
}
```

Comment: print_r ($oku[IL_ADI]); use this with single quote print_r ($oku['IL_ADI']);

Comment: Thanks for fast responseI've tried that and no data returned.

Comment: just show your table structure

Comment: Is `PDO` or `IL_ADI` undefined?

Comment: You can't use directly IL_ADI, without apostrophes is a constant, no a string. Remember also, PHP is case-sensitive, if your table row name is il_adi, you need to use 'il_adi', not 'IL_ADI'. For more data, show your table structure as suggested by @AmitGaud

Comment: @Amit Gaud Table name is iller and has just two columns  rownumber and IL_ADI , engine myISAM, collation utf8_turkish_ci

Comment: @PeterMader IL_ADI undefined

Comment: *"I've tried $oku['IL_ADI'] and no data was returned."* - then your query failed. Plus seeing `("<option name='ilsec' value=''")` this tells me that that isn't your full code. You're not telling/showing us something. The `value=''` does just that; "no value".

Comment: *"utf8, otherwise I'm getting characters problem"* - Consult https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: @Fred-ii-  I'm trying the IL_ADI data to show in the select option field if it helps i can post full code. But I don't want to take your more time. I'm reading the link you've send.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r ("<option name='ilsec' value=''");
```

to

```
print_r ("<option name='ilsec' value=''>");
```

I've forgot to put **>** .
After adding that the data has come.
But other problems came along:)
Thank you everyone for the quick answers.